# React router doesnt work on Nginx reverse proxy with pm2

Tags: reactjs, nginx, pm2

I am trying to host a react application. 
The application works fine at my local computer including routing.
I uploaded a ubuntu nginx web server. I served as a `pm2` service.
I configured as a reverse proxy for react application at `8080` port.It works only main page. It couldn't routing any react route.

For example when browse `http://my_react_app/admin` then it returns `404 not found` page

Here is my `ngninx` `default` configuration.

```
upstream react_app {
 server 127.0.0.1:8080;
 keepalive 64;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name my_react_app;

    location / {
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
      proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
      proxy_http_version 1.1;
      proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
      proxy_set_header Connection “upgrade”;
      proxy_max_temp_file_size 0;
      proxy_pass http://react_app/;
      proxy_redirect off;
      proxy_read_timeout 240s;
   }

}
```

Please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

When servering with pm2, try this command: `pm2 serve directory_name --spa`. The tag --spa is for serving single page applications. Ensure your pm2 version is 3.5.0.